# Can any function on naturals be interpolated to a smooth function on reals?

Tags: functions, derivatives, interpolation

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be an arbitrary function from naturals to naturals. Is it always possible to find a function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f(n) = g(n)$, and
2. $g \in C^\infty$?

I'm asking because I was trying to prove a result about the ratios of functions from naturals to naturals and it occurred to me that if I could always interpolate to get back smooth functions from integers to integers, I could conceivably use l'Hopital's rule to resolve the limits.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a $C^\infty$-function $\phi$ s.t. $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi(x)=0$ for (say) $|x|>1/3$. Take $f(x)=\sum_n g(n)\phi(x-n)$ (sum is infinite, but at every point at most one term contributes).

Comment: Just as a heads-up, I should warn you that trying to convert to real functions to use L'Hôpital is likely to wind up circular; your results will almost certainly depend on the limit of the integer ratio...

Answer (score 3):

Whittaker–Shannon interpolation, using the $sinc$ function, achieves that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin\pi(x-n)}{\pi(x-n)}.$$

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Lanczos interpolation. Can you elaborate a bit more about how you would do this and why it would work?

Comment: Sorry, this other entry is more appropriate. Read the article.

Answer (score 1):

First, one needs an analytic function such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(n)=n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z  \setminus\{0\}$. The [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) can be useful for that:
$$\operatorname{sinc}x  = \frac{\sin x}x, ~~ x\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$$
$$\operatorname{sinc}0  = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x = 1$$

Note that $\operatorname{sinc}0=1$and $\mathrm{sinc} (n\pi) = 0$ for $n\in\mathbb Z  \setminus\{0\}$, as needed. Therefore, one could construct
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \operatorname{sinc}[(n-x)\pi] f(n)
$$
and have $g(n) = f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

However, this would not in general even converge for any choice $f(n)$, and even if it converges, it might not have all the derivatives (i.e. the derivatives might not converge). In order to fix this, the function used to construct $g(x)$ should be modified to fall sufficiently fast. Just replacing this function with a different one which would be the same for every $n$ can work for a wider class of functions $f(n)$, but it will not work in general, regardless of the choice. The modification should depend on individual values $f(n)$. Something like this:

$$
g(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \operatorname{sinc}[(n-x)\pi] e^{-f(n)^2(n-x)^2} f(n)
$$

That way, no matter how absurdly fast $f(n)$ grows (e.g. something that needs to be written using [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) or [Conway chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) or worse, like the [TREE function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TREE)), $g(x)$ will converge everywhere and it will even be in $C^\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sequence of points $z_n$ in an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$ without an accumulation point, and $\alpha_n$ a sequence of values, there exists a holomorphic function $\phi$ on $\Omega$ with $\phi(z_n)= \alpha_n$, for all $n$. Now, if $z_n$ and $\alpha_n$ are real, we can take $\phi$ real on $\Omega\cap \mathbb{R}$ ( take
$\frac{\phi(z) + \bar \phi(\bar z)}{2}$).
This is a standard result in complex analysis.