# Which smooth, real-argument fast growing functions are known?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, big-numbers

Related to [N-ation of N by N](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799267/solution-for-fractional-operation-n-ation-of-n-by-n)

I would like to know of a function `SFG(x)` with following properties:

- Grows at least as fast as Ackermann sequence
- Defined for all reals greater than 1
- Has inverse function defined for all reals after 1
- Smooth for all parameter values after 1
- Easy to compute for commonly used numbers (e.g. Planck volume to approximate observable universe volume in Planck volumes)
- Supported with mathematical apparatus to make it possible to compare SFG(x) with a given non-smooth fast growing function for a given x

Commonly cited fast growing functions are Busy Beaver numbers and TREE, but they fail almost all of bullet points above. Once there is a sufficiently fast growing function, all other fast growing functions' known values can be approximated as SFG(x), where x is relatively small real number. Then math can be made in SFG-notation instead of natural numbers-based notation.

Comment: The standard scale for fast growing functions, which can be used to name large integers, is [the Fast-Growing Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy). The Ackermann function is essentially the $\omega$'th level (least infinite ordinal number), and pushing the levels far into the unimaginatively high realms winds up being a problem in constructing notations for large countable (and also recursive) ordinal numbers, at least if you want some kind "from below" large integer naming method. For smooth versions, use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/811480/13130).